# Jquery serialize() method doesn't work

Tags: jquery, serialization

I have a basic html and a javascript function as below. When I serialize the form by form Id, it works. But I want to serialize a piece of html content that doesnt a form such as `$('.FormReference').serialize()`.

What can't I do this?

```
    $(function () {

        $('#btnLogin').click(function (event) {

            alert($('#form1').serialize());
        });

    });


<form id="form1" runat="server" action="">
    <div>
        <table class="FormReference">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="_Username" name="Username" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="_Password" name="Password" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="button" id="btnLogin" value="Login" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: [`.serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) only works on forms (or collections of form elements). `$('.FormReference')` is a table, not a form (or a form element).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> The `.serialize()` method can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form elements, such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>`. However, it is typically easier to select the `<form>` tag itself for serialization:

So you have two options:

```
$('.FormReference').closest('form').serialize(); // serialize the whole form
$('.FormReference').find('input, select, textarea, button').serialize(); // serialize only elements contained within .FormReference
$('.FormReference').find(':input').serialize(); // shorter, but less efficient, alternative
```

Comment: What about `$('.FormReference').find(':input')` :-P